# "Requested Range Not Satisfiable" http get request error in Android error 416

Tags: android, json, http, get

i tried below code but it give error 
Requested Range Not Satisfiable

```
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
url = url.replace(" ", "+");
//  url += "?" + paramString;
Log.e("-------------------------->", paramString.toString());
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
Log.e("url--- is:-",""+url);
httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Ranges","none");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: Why are you setting "Accept-Ranges" in the request-header? This is a response-header field which should be coming from the server.

Comment: @Danny_ds without set header i got below error  "Requested Range Not Satisfiable"

Comment: got solutions by adding httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");